# perl looking to format number with leading +/- and round to 2 decimal places

Tags: perl, format, numbers

I'm looking to format a number to have a leading +/- plus round to two decimals. Example:

```
1.01333
```

I can use `sprintf "%2f", mynumber` for the decimal option

I can use `sprintf "%d", mynumber` for the leading +/-

But I cannot seem to find a way to combine them so I have a final number of

```
+1.01
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

```
sprintf "%+.2f"
```

The '+' indicates to print the sign even if positive, and '.2f' prints 2 digits after the decimal point and left-justifies as many digits before the decimal point as there are. If you want it right-justified, then use something like

```
sprintf "%+9.2f"
```

Comment: I guess I should have added that if the number is negative, keep the negative value and loose the "+".  This solution appears to put a "+" at the front of all numbers.

Comment: First off, I just noticed that I forgot to add the '%' to the examples. I've edited that now.

Comment: Second, the '+' format modifier outputs a '+' for positive values and a '-' for negative values

Comment: Ah .. I noticed on the original post the "%" was missing and I assumed "+%.2f" as opposed to "%+.2f".  Your editted update appears to be giving me the results I'm looking for -- thank you.